# jsonwebtoken package fails to verify user Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityToken result

Tags: jwt, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-js-helpers

I'm developing an Outlook web add-in.

I'm trying to verify a token that I'm passing to server side, through a `node.js` library, but it's failing and I can't understand why.

This is what I'm doing to retrieve the user identity token.

```
Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(function(result) {
    result.value // contains the token.
    // send this value to server side, which I can see that it's working.
})
```

On the server side, I retrieve the token and do below:

```
token; // contains the token passed from the web-app.
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const request = require('request');

let decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});

// Get the key, we'll need this later since we'll have to
// find the matching key from the config file.
let key = decoded.header.x5t;
let amurl = JSON.parse(decoded.payload.appctx).amurl;

// Make a request to the url to get the configuration json file.
request(amurl, {}, (err, response, body) => {
    let keys = JSON.parse(body).keys;

    // Filter the keys so we get the one which we can verify.
    let s = keys.filter(t => t.keyinfo.x5t === key);
    let cert = s[0].keyvalue.value;

    // Fails the verification.
    console.log(jwt.verify(token, cert));
});
```

Just to clarify, I'm retrieving the token correctly and this npm package seems to be functioning fine for other jwt tokens. (So it's not really a configuration issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the answer to this question.

Just to re-iterate the problem was:

1. `Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityToken` method returns a jwt token.
2. When decoded this token contains an `amurl` field which points to the public certificate as a text.
3. When `jsonwebtoken.verify(token, certText)` is called, it's failing with the message `invalid algorithm` (even if you specify the algorithm from the token's header)

The problem was the **formatting** of the certificate text. `jsonwebtoken` package was looking for a particular formatting (splitted with 64 characters across each line along with the certificate begin and certificate end lines, so when formatted with method below - it started working properly.

The original code is taken from here: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/68 and formatted slightly to fit the needs.

```
/**
 * @param {string} key - The certificate value retrieved from amurl property.
 */
formatKey: function(key) {
    const beginKey = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
    const endKey = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    const sanitizedKey = key.replace(beginKey, '').replace(endKey, '').replace('\n', '')

    const keyArray = sanitizedKey.split('').map((l, i) => {
      const position = i + 1
      const isLastCharacter = sanitizedKey.length === position
      if(position % 64 === 0 || isLastCharacter) {
        return l + '\n'
      }
      return l
    })

    return `${beginKey}\n${keyArray.join('')}${endKey}\n`
  }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to resolve your issue.